# Why I am getting this error while applying this code. I have enclosed the error and code below?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, stack, queue

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.front=self.rear=-1
        self.Q=list()
        self.size=size
    def empty(self):
        return self.front==self.rear
    def full(self):
        return self.rear==self.size-1
    def enqueue(self,item):
        if self.full():
            print("Stack Overflow")
            return
        else:
            self.rear+=1
            self.Q[self.rear]=item
    def dequeue(self):
        if self.empty():
            print("Stack Underflow")
            return 
        else:
            a=-1
            self.front+=1
            a=self.Q[self.front]
            return a
```

[Error I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqRg3.png)

Comment: Your Q is empty with 0 elements and you are trying to modify  element with position 1  which doesn't exist.

Comment: The Above Code is Queue Implementation using Array

Comment: Yes I figured but my point is still valid. You should append or define the size before-hand

Comment: I could append , but I didn't do this by using append method and your second question i have defined size before hand in my syntax.

Comment: You have defined `size` but the arr is still has length 0. `self.Q=list()` with a size it should be something like `self.Q = [None] * 5`. but it doesn't make much sense to have fixed length queue use `append`. also `collections.deque` exists so you can use that as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is pretty straight forward. You are getting an `IndexError` which means that you are attempting to read/write to a non-existent index in the list. The key to fixing this is initialization of the list with either `None` or `0` in the `__init__` method.

#### Proposed fix

---

```
def __init__(self, size):
    self.front = self.rear=-1
    self.size = size

    self.Q = [None for i in range(self.size)]    # Initializes the list with `None` values
```

Here, the list is filled with `size` number of `None` value. This makes accessing of values with index possible.

Comment: Thank u so much !!. My code is running , actually i forget to add none values.

Comment: If this helps, you can accept this answer and upvote it... :)

Comment: This will still cause an issue after a few call to `enqueue`; there should be a mechanism to resize the queue, or at the very least to recenter the queue because it is drifting when the user alternates between enqueuing and dequeuing.

Comment: @TanayDuggad After applying Melvin's fix, try the following code: `q = Queue(10)`
 `for i in range(20):  print(i)  q.enqueue(i)  q.dequeue()`

Comment: @TanayDuggad A user would expect it to work well, because there is never more than one element in the queue. Yet after adding and removing the tenth element, the Queue overflows and it's impossible to add any more elements. Do you understand why?

Comment: @Stef Based on current logic and usage of `front` and `rear`, this solution seems to work just fine. I can understand that this could lead to Overflow issues for large enqueue and dequeue operations but even if I were to dynamically shift the values, it would just result in unwanted results like inclusion of `None` when fetching the value (again due to the way `front` & `rear` is used). This answer includes only **minimum changes** that can be done to get it up and running. Also, one workaround would be to specify a large enough size.

Comment: Specifying a size larger than needed to actually hold the content of the queue sounds excessive if you're planning on lots of queue/dequeue operations. One workaround would be to treat the list as a circular buffer: if `rear > size`, replace `rear` with `rear % size`.

Comment: @Stef I couldn't agree more. Also, as I said it's only a workaround and is thus not recommended. A circular list would also work but if overflow were the issue, then it would just be better off to use `append()` and `pop()` right away without any of the extra bells and whistles. I think the OP has a constraint for the problem and is just concerned with getting this to work. If the problem were directed towards performance or efficiency, those extra info would have been the way to go :)

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the error since the list has no elements inside it.

You cannot use list[i] if the list does not have an element at index `i`

If you want to add an element, you can use `list.append(element)`

Your function becomes:

```
def enqueue(self,item):
        if self.full():
            print("Stack Overflow")
            return
        else:
            self.rear+=1
            self.Q.append(item)
```

If you can explain more about why do you you use rear front etc, I can help you more.

Comment: My Code is running finally as I have forget to add None Values to indexes while making array. Thanku for your contribution.

Comment: I have added rear and front because we can add at rear index while we can pop from top index following FIFO principle of Queue. This results in O(1) time complexity